# Getting error in cv::imshow() - ASSERT: "false" in file qasciikey.cpp, line 501

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-14.04, imshow

I am getting this error whenever I call cv::waitKey():

```
ASSERT: "false" in file qasciikey.cpp, line 501
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. I am running on an Ubuntu Server 14.04 EC2 instance connected through MobaXterm on Windows.
If I run all of the same code on a normal ubuntu machine, all works great.

This is the line where this happens:

```
char key = cvWaitKey(33);
```

Comment: When i originally build OpenCV I used the flag WITH_QT=ON. I simply ended up building OpenCV with WITH_QT=OFF and it worked great.

Comment: I got the error when didn't change my keyboard to English.

Comment: I got the same error in the same circumstance. It does not always happen.

Answer (score 13):

A workaround in MobaXterm is to uncheck "Unix-compatible keyboard" in X11 settings.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
pip install qtconsole
```

I solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not trying to get the glory here but I think this deserves a proper answer.

As @George mentioned in the comment when my input was not from an **English keyboard** but used some other locale then this error occurs. I have seen other proposed reasons for this error but I guess this is a quite usual case since the error reports:

> ASSERT: "false"